# var Crypto = require('crypto'); require is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-directives

Getting error as require is not a function,trying to use crypto js functions into typescript component

```
// Load modules
'use strict';
var Crypto = require('crypto');
```

Comment: Executing it in non-NodeJS env without any Module loader?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `require` within angular applications, you'll need to do it like so:

```
import * as Crypto from "crypto-browserify";
```

Note that I've used the `crypto-browserify` package, because the code will be run in a browser.